# my nodejs cannot connect to mongodb docker with environmental variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to mongodb from nodejsb

but I am getting authentication error

```
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
2023-04-08 12:13:18     at Connection.onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:210:30)
```

This is my connection string

MONGO = "mongodb://admin:password@mongo:27017/marble_arch"

This is my docker-compose file
In the docker compose I created a network and placed all the components inside the network. I use mongodb service name on the nodejs connection string but I am getting authentication error.

I don't know why the error.

```
version: "3"

services:
  front-end:
    container_name: frontend
    image: marble-arch-frontend
    build: ./my-app
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    networks:
      - marble-arch
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: backend
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 7500:7500
    networks:
      - marble-arch
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - marble-arch
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
    networks:
      - marble-arch
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
      - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
networks:
  marble-arch: {}

volumes:
  mongodb:
  mongodb_config:
```